# Quick questions about showing that defining poset over a vector space is a category.

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

The following question is taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

Exercise:  Let $X$ be a vector space and let $\leq$ be the partial ordering on $X$ of exercise 1.  Verify that the following data define a category $\textbf{K}.$  The objects of $\textbf{K}$ are the elements of $X$.  For $x,y$ in $X,$ $\textbf{K}(x,y)=\{\lambda\mid \lambda x\leq y\}.$ Composition is ordinary multiplication.  Observe that there are many pairs of objects $(x,y)$ such that $\textbf{K}(x,y)=\emptyset.$

I would like to know how composition works, since to show that the object $\textbf{K}$ is a category, i have to use composition of morphism.

Is the composition of morphism for the mapping $\textbf{K}(x,y)\times \textbf{K}(y,z)\rightarrow \textbf{K}(y,z)$ defined as $\lambda x\leq z$ or ${\lambda}^2 x\leq z$?, where we have $\textbf{K}(x,y)=\{\lambda\mid \lambda x\leq y\}$  and $\textbf{K}(y,z)=\{\lambda\mid \lambda y\leq z\}.$  Also, how does one get $\textbf{K}(x,y)=\emptyset?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider two morphisms $\lambda \colon x \to y$ and $\mu \colon y \to z$, i.e. $\lambda x \leq y$ and $\mu y \leq z$. Then, as $\mu\lambda x \leq \mu y \leq z$, we have $\mu \lambda \colon x \to z$. Hence, the composition $${\bf K}(y,z) \times {\bf K}(x,y) \stackrel \circ \to {\bf K}(x,z)$$ is defined by $(\mu,\lambda) \mapsto \mu\lambda$.

Comment: @azif00 would it be correct to say that $\textbf{K}(x,z)=\{\mu\lambda\mid (\mu\lambda)  x \leq z\}$?